# Stanford POS tagger: -filelist option not working

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run the Stanford POS tagger on a series of files, but I'm having trouble with the `-filelist option`. Whenever I run the command with `-filelist`, I'm asked to type text, which is the default when no files are specified. But the filelist is given with its full path (the file exists there--I double-checked), and that file contains the names of two files, again full paths, one per line (also double-checked and they're there).

My call, from Linux (Mint) terminal:

```
java -mx2g -classpath stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger -filelist /home/kevin/filelist.test
```

(I haven't included an output option for the sake of highlighting the problem. I have, of course, tried various ones.) Of course, I've moved the filelist into the working directory and various other potential remedies that didn't work.

Note that if I switch `-filelist` to `-textFile`, it will tag that file, even though they're just file locations--which is useless but it shows that everything else works.

Again, I'm not getting any error. It just doesn't recognize the filelist and prompts me to type the text to be tagged. Tried on two different machines, albeit with the same or similar OS, with the same problem.

Can't really supply any reproducible code, but I'm happy to provide any further information upon request. And please note I have no experience in Java.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the standalone POS tagger distribution doesn't have a filelist option.  You want to use the full pipeline.

There is plenty of documentation here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html